# jQuery UI Autocomplete up/down arrows not showing item selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to get the jQuery autocomplete to work and it doesn't show/highlight the item when using up/down arrows. It wasn't doing anything at all with the up/down arrows until I put `event.preventDefault();` in the `focus` event. But now it will travel up and down the autocomplete list using the arrows, but the items are not highlighted like they are when you 'hover' over them with the mouse. So you can select an item with the arrows, you just can't tell which one you're on because it doesn't highlight them as the arrows move you through the list.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your school name..." name="school" id="school" class="schoolpicker school-input text-center form-control form-control-md-lg">

        $("#school").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Search/Find",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { prefix: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data);
                        $('#FindLoans').prop("disabled", true);
                    }
                });
            },
            appendTo: ".form",
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $("span#SchoolName").text(ui.item.Name);
                $("#school").val(ui.item.Name);
                $('#FindLoans').removeAttr("disabled");
                $.ajax({ -- get data here --});
                return false;
            },
            focus: function (event, ui) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $("#" + ui.item.SchoolID).attr("title", ui.item.Name + " - " + ui.item.Location);                    
            },
            autoFocus: true,
            selectFirst: true,
            change: function (event, ui) {}
        }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            return $("<li id=" + item.SchoolID + ">")
                .data("ui-menu-divider", item)
                .append(item.Name)
                .appendTo(ul);
        };
```

I've tried using these classes from another answer, but they don't work:

```
 .ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover, .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus {
        cursor: pointer;
        background: #14aecf;
    }

    .ui-menu-item:active .ui-state-active, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-active, a.ui-button:active, .ui-button:active, .ui-button.ui-state-active:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        background: #14aecf;
    }
```

This is my hover CSS:

```
   .ui-menu-item {
        font-size: 18px;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 10px;
    }

        .ui-menu-item:hover {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #14aecf;
            border-color: #14aecf;
            font-size: 18px;
            text-align: left;
        }
```

Any ideas why the up/down isn't highlighting the items?

This is the jQuery UI CSS I'm using. I'm also using Bootstrap if that makes a difference. It is before the UI CSS.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
```

Also, without putting the hove CSS, the regular jQuery UI hover for the autocomplete doesn't work. I have these three files, am I missing a CSS file or something?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.structure.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.theme.css"/>
```

Comment: Most likely due to `focus` event being prevented.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it is the end part of my code that was causing the issue:

```
.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        return $("<li id=" + item.SchoolID + ">")
            .data("ui-menu-divider", item)
            .append(item.Name)
            .appendTo(ul);
    }
```

I found that code somewhere so I used it and it worked fine the way I had it set up except for the up/down arrows.

What I did was remove that and add the items with a `$map` instead:

```
           source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Search/Find",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { prefix: request.term },
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#FindLoans').prop("disabled", true);
                        response($.map(data,
                            function(obj) {
                                return {
                                    label: obj.Name,
                                    value: obj.Name,
                                    description: obj.Location,
                                    id: obj.SchoolID
                                };
                            }));
                    }
                });
            },
            appendTo: ".form",
```

And this has fixed everything... up/down arrows are now fine.